# How do i use a function w TWO parameters to convert to ANY currency in program? [C]

Tags: c, function, parameters, clang, currency

This is in C language

As the title says how do i convert to ANY value in my currency within a function using only two parameters? Currently i have one.  I've looked around the web and haven't found ANY solution. And my puny brain simply cannot think of any working formula for this.

This is my code at the moment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float convertToDollars(float sek);

int main() {
    float sek;
    float usd;
        printf("How much money in SEK?: ");
        scanf("%f", &sek);
       usd = convertToDollars(sek);
        printf("%.2f SEK - %.2f USD\n", sek, usd);


    getchar(); // used so output window not exit prematurely
    getchar(); // -,,-
    return 0;
}

float convertToDollars(float sek) { //no scanf or printf allowed in function
    return sek * 0.1000;
}
```

It only uses one currency conversion and that is converting the Swedish Krona (SEK) into American Dollar (USD). The function needs to work for all possible exchange rates (which is then given as an argument to the function at the call).

The function should take two parameters: the number of Swedish kronor and the exchange rate (the exchange rate will vary depending on the currency to be converted to).

Comment: I don't see why you can't use `float convertToDollars(float amount, float rate)`

Comment: A general advice - do not use floating point types for currencies. These are naturally represented by integer dollar/cent amounts.

Comment: i can use float rate, but how do i apply it to work for all possible exchange rates, not just one exchange rate?

Comment: You can have an array of exchange rates which you index into. You pass the one you want to the function.